# Problems installing a specific version of Ionic with Node

Tags: ionic-framework

How can I create a project with ionic 5 using "ionic start". I have Ionic cli version 6.20.8 and Node 16.14.0 and the projects are created with ionic 7.

What I did was to install another version of the cli with `"npm install -g ionic@5.4.16"` but it installs version 6.20.8, the same I tried with the command `"ionic start myApp tabs --type=angular --capacitor --version=5.4.16"` but it is still created with version 7 of Ionic.

Comment: Why do you want to use an old and out-of-date version of the framework? What problem does this solve for you? Also you are not using the right command to install the CLI. Please refer to https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cli

Comment: I need to use version 5 of ionic to create the projects with the structure of ionic 5 in which the app.module.ts and the app.routing.module.ts are used, since in the most recent versions it is no longer used, and the projects that I have use that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not **need** to use version 5 of Ionic to achieve your goal. In fact, I would recommend against a version 2 releases behind.

A workaround would be as such:

1. Create a base angular project
   `npx -p @angular/cli ng new myApp`
2. Go into the newly created project
   `cd myApp`
3. Init the project as an Ionic app
   `npx @ionic/cli init "My App" --type=angular`

This will create a project with the latest and greatest **and** include the module structure you want. **However**, it doesn't create the tabs. You will have to add this by hand.

If you **really** want to do Ionic 5 **and** have tabs auto added you can use the old package name and do `npx ionic start myApp tabs --type=angular --capacitor`

But speaking from experience, if you are doing any kind of professional work, I strongly recommend that you make the commitment to staying on the latest versions and libraries for the sake of security/bug fixes, build processes, and long-term maintainability.